# Multi-expression display equation: and or comma?

Tags: math-mode, equations, amsmath, typography, subequations

Example:

[image]

In display equations that contain two separate expressions in a single line, which we would normally read off verbally with an "and" conjunction, does it make sense to use a comma or an "and" in typesetting them?

If we follow the rule that we should treat math as part of the text, I lead myself to feel that we would use "and" although I think I've seen the comma more often. I tried looking at Knuth and Chicago Manual of Style, but couldn't quite find the style answer.

Comment: This question seems to more properly belong on `math.stackexchange`, since it's about style and not really about LaTeX presentation.

Comment: @barbarabeeton - I tried to give my answer a (La)TeX angle by mentioning `\quad` as the preferred spacing amount for display-math material.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just imagine that you were using inline math instead of display math to express the claim. Then, `and` would doubtless be the correct conjunction. What's correct for inline math should be correct for display math as well. For display math, though, you should probably insert `\quad` instead of ordinary inter-word space on either side of the word `and`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Inline math:

The variables $x$ and $y$ obey the following constraints: $x+y<1$ and $x-y=2$.

Display math:

The variables $x$ and $y$ obey the following constraints: 
\[
x+y<1 \quad\mbox{and}\quad x-y=2.
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Great! Sorry, why use \mbox and not \text for the "and"?

Comment: @AimForClarity I'd go for `\text`; it's slightly less efficient, but semantics are important.

Comment: @AimForClarity - To use `\text`, it's necessary to load the `amsmath` package. I wanted to make the code above as absolutely minimalist as possible, which meant not loading `amsmath`. I agree with @egreg, though, that `\text` is semantically better than `\mbox`.

Comment: @AimForClarity In Addition, if you have thee formulas, I would set no space between a formula and a comma like `x<1,\quad x+y<1 \quad\mbox{and}\quad x-y=2.` (display mode). This is implied by Micos answer.

Comment: @CampanIgnis - I see Mico didn't use a thin or thick space before the punctuation in the display equation either, so that would make sense. However, I seem to work in a community that believes in using \; before the punctuation in a display equation, so that there is no confusion about the formula and punctuation when they touch.  In that case, would it still be logical to use `x<1\;, \quad x+y<1\;,  \quad \text{and} \quad x-y=2 \;.`. This is almost becoming a question of its own.

Comment: @AimForClarity I am typing my notes for 20 years and can tell you: use `\;` before commas and periods, even if some are yelling at you. It is way better to let them yell than having a reader confuse `\[x_i,\quad \dots\]` with `\[x_{i^\prime}\quad \dots\]` and so on. And type differential d's upright. Those who read the results will appreciate it.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Touché! In addition, I forgot a Harvard comma.